# Paging on Azure Table Storage

Tags: azure, azure-table-storage

I was playing with an idea that I yet haven't had time to test myself and therefore wanted to bring it up here with a few initial questions.

Lets say we have a very large table in Azure Table Storage that is altered very rarely, but its still so large that Azure Table Storage is the right fit for storing the data.

One of missing features on table storage is that there is no paging and you have to do range queries.

When iterating all rows in the table using the next tokens. Is these next tokens persistence over time (when the table do not change) such I could create a paging table with all next tokens?

(My understanding is that a next token is just a row/partitionkey starting point in the table).

Having the paging table could provide a meaning of looking up data in fixed ranges.